# OpenCV java project runs in Eclipse but not in Command line

Tags: java, opencv, noclassdeffounderror

I downloaded OpenCV for Java and added the jar and libraries to the project in Eclipse and it works fine.

But when I try to run the .class file where my `main(String args[])` is, it throws

```
> java MainActivity 1 5 8
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core
    at HoleFiller.<init>(HoleFiller.java:29)
    at MainActivity._fixHole(MainActivity.java:100)
    at MainActivity._getImageNames(MainActivity.java:92)
    at MainActivity._authArgTypes(MainActivity.java:66)
    at MainActivity.main(MainActivity.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Core
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

It crashes on this line

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

Is there any way to include the .jar file in the project so it will run from the command line?

Comment: You're not adding anything to your runtime classpath. Learn about Maven or Gradle and use one of them to manage your dependencies for you, including for launching.

Answer (score 0):

When you run within Eclipse, then the IDE will automatically handle the dependencies, but when you run from the commadnd line, then you need you to handle it your self.

Follow these commands to do so:

1. When compiling:

> javac -cp path/to/opencv.jar YourProgram.java

2. When running:

> java -cp path/to/opencv.jar:. -Djava.library.path=path/to/opencv.dll
>   YourProgram

And you can add the .dll path to the system path, then it will automatically get access to it.